# How to replace tag and leave its content?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html code :

`<i>https://www.example.com/01.png</i>`

I want to replace the i tag with another tag and leave the same content
eg.

`<a><img src=" + my url + "></a>`

I did try, but it didn't work

`var a = $ (this)، b = a.text (). trim ()، c = a.html ()؛ $ ("i") .replaceWith ('<a>' + c + "</a>")؛`

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: I did try, but it didn't work
` var a = $(this), b = a.text().trim(), c = a.html();
$( "i" ).replaceWith( '<a>' + c + "</a>" );
`

Comment: You have typed the code that you used on the topic

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the URL between `i` tags using a regular expression and then create `a` and `img` element and set the extracted URL string as a value of the `src` attribute on the `img` element.

```js
const regex = /(https:[^<]+)/g;
const str = '<i>https://www.example.com/01.png</i>';

const matches = str.match(regex);
const result = `<a><img src="${matches[0]}"/></a>`;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regular expression like this :

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('<i>', '<otherTag>');
```